# What can I purchase with items I obtain from fulfilling Tokyo Airport cargo shipments?

Tags: ios, simcity-buildit

What can I purchase with items I obtain from fulfilling Tokyo Airport cargo shipments? So far I have a single lucky cat. I'm not sure if there are other items that you can receive as well.

Comment: So far it looks like I can use them while upgrading Tokyo residential areas, but I'm not sure if they have any use for unlocking special services later on in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the items you receive fulfilling cargo shipments (lantern, bonsai tree, lucky cat) can be used only to build and upgrade Tokyo Town Zone residential areas.